# Finding Romanian ancestor's UK naturalisation date?

Tags: 20th-century, united-kingdom, naturalization

My Grandfather (Stan Cancea) came over from Romania in 1908 and we believe was made a British citizen after the 2nd World War.  Unfortunately the National Archives cannot find any record, apparently some papers were lost or damaged.  My Grandma received  her naturalisation in 1943 (having to become a Romanian to marry) but we have hit a dead end.

Comment: I've used Canadian and U.S. voter's lists to estimate and corroborate naturalization dates for 20th century immigrants. (Citizenship is required to vote in provincial/state  and national elections). Ancestry has a number of UK county Electoral Registers, with varying date ranges, but these have a number of purposes. Read the database descriptions for more detail and to see if these apply to your problem.

Comment: Have you tried the search with the name Stanislas?

Comment: The London Gazette would normally print a notice.  Here's an example page showing naturalisations in May 1939: https://www.thegazette.co.uk/London/issue/34634/page/3881 (my grandfather, who came over from Germany, is featured).  I can't locate your grandfather by searching, but I suspect he's there somewhere.  His name could be mis-spelled (or not properly indexed) - it might be worth trying some variations on this search.

Comment: I would vote to close this question because it is unclear what you are asking. Is the question about naturalization in the UK or in Romania?  Why is the country of origin relevant to the question?

Comment: @JanMurphy - the question is about a Romanian (by birth) naturalizing in the UK. His wife had lost her (presumably) UK ciitzenship when she married the immigrant, and repatriated later.

Comment: @JonnyPerl I think you should post that comment as an answer.

Comment: @bgwiehle But wouldn't that be the case for anyone? I.e. there's no special rule that says someone loses their UK citizenship if and only if their new spouse is from Romania.  Therefore why should this Q be tagged for Romania?

Comment: @JanMurphy I was responding to the "unclear" part of your earlier comment. Back in the early 1900s when this couple married (as also in Canada & USA), the husband's nationality applied to the wife. The OP was providing background when she referenced Romania. You are probably right that the Romania TAG is irrelevant.

Comment: (@JanMurphy I think there is some though not great) value to having a [tag:Romania] tag on this question so that it may find its way into the filters if those with British Romanian ancestry. This is pure speculation but maybe they know of an organization that celebrated and recorded the naturalization of those in their community.

Answer (score 2):

The London Gazette would normally print a notice. Here's an example page showing naturalisations in May 1939: http://thegazette.co.uk/London/issue/34634/page/3881 (my grandfather, who came over from Germany, is featured).

I can't locate your grandfather by searching, but I suspect he's there somewhere. His name could be mis-spelled (or not properly indexed) - it might be worth trying some variations on this search.

[unfortunately the Gazette site search doesn't seem to allow wildcards but you might have some luck doing a Google search on with site:thegazette.co.uk, as the individual pages do seem to be indexed]